# Looking for guidance on a Fourier integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Working with a Fourier transform problem, I've encountered the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-a^2x^2+ibx\right)}{x^2+c^2}dx
$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real coefficients.  Mathematica claims that this has no closed-form solution, but I suspect (hope?) that's not the case.  Unfortunately, my background in complex analysis is limited to some panic-studying I did to make it through a field theory course a decade ago.  I've spent the weekend dusting that off, but am still stumped...

I know there's a pole at $z=ci$.  If I take (to me) the obvious extension of the integral to the complex plane by simply replacing $x$ with $z$, I can even calculate its residue as:

$$
\frac{\exp\left(a^2c^2-bc\right)}{2ci}
$$

My hope was to integrate over a semicircle in the positive half-plane, and use this residue to get the integral along the real axis.  However, with this extension, the integral over the semicircle of radius R doesn't seem to be zero (or possibly even converge) with R going to infinity -- or at least, Jordan's lemma doesn't give me any reason to believe so, since the $-a^2z^2$ part becomes unfriendly on the imaginary axis.

I vaguely recall there being a strategy for dealing with this sort of problem.  I specifically recall the strategy not being to use $zz^*$, since explicit dependence on the complex conjugate was a no-go.  For the life of me, though, I can't recall what the strategy *was*.

If anybody can (a) refresh my memory on this; (b) give a solution method; or (c) explain why no closed form solution exists, that would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gaussian term makes complex analysis iffy.  This integral may be done much  more easily using the convolution theorem.

To begin, note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x^2} e^{i k x} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{-k^2/(4 a)}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{x^2+c^2} = \frac{\pi}{c} e^{-c |k|}$$

The integral sought is the convolution of these transforms.  That is,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{x^2+c^2} e^{i b x} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \frac{\pi}{c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \,e^{-k^2/(4 a)} \, e^{-c |b-k|} $$

This integral is very doable, despite what Mathematica says.  For the time being, I will spare you the details, which involve splitting the integral about $k=b$ and rescaling to get a nice form.  The result is that the sought-after integral is

$$\frac{\pi}{c} e^{a c^2} \left [e^{-b c} \left (1+\text{erf}\left (\frac{b-2 a c}{2 \sqrt{a}} \right ) \right ) + e^{b c} \left (1-\text{erf}\left (\frac{b+2 a c}{2 \sqrt{a}} \right ) \right )\right ]  $$

where erf is the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

**NOTE**

My $a$ is the OP's $a^2$ - this was not intentional, but to get an answer the OP wants, sub $a^2$ for $a$ in the above result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and very informative reply!  I wonder if something has gone slightly awry in the details?  I've done a test with $\left(a,b,c\right)=\left(2,0.5,3\right)$ using your $a$, and numerically get an integral of about 0.13 (which seems sensible for these parameters and the Gaussian envelope), but am getting a value of $1.7\times 10^7$ using your final analytic form.

Comment: @JasonCooper: That should be $e^{a c^2}$, not $e^{2 a c^2}$.  My apologies.

Comment: @JasonCooper: I get about $0.112$ for my expression with your parameters.